# Salesforce UI gets distorted using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

using bootstrap 3.2.2 with the vf page shows the page header(Conatining standard tabs) and side bar appears zoomed. This distorts the UI. Any way where I can use bootstrap without distorting the salesforce standard UI. I am using bootstrap cdn complete css - //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
complete js - //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/using-twitter-bootstrap-3-alongside-with-standard-salesforce-stylesheet

Comment: @mohith I went through this link but have no idea how to "recompiling the bootstrap LESS files after changing the bootstrap less file by wrapping it within a "domain", i.e. .scopedBootstrap{ import "variables.less"; import "mixins.less"; …. }"  Could you please explain in detail the steps needed to be followed